# JavaFX CSS how do I blend Text color to appear as white when a progress bar overlaps it?

Tags: css, javafx, progress-bar, javafx-css

I have this image of a progress bar:

[image: Progress-Bar]

I am trying to make the text change color as the bar overlaps it. I have no idea how to do this in JavaFX since it is not as flexible as the known CSS. I tried to use different blend modes provided but no use I couldn't manage to get the white color I wanted. Basically, there is no code to show since I don't know where to start. Is there any workaround?

Comment: not supported, afaik - could be mainly due to the fact that Text doesn't support segmented coloring, if so then a custom skin wouldn't help neither

Comment: You could probably use derivation and laddering to do this. Sorry, I don't have a concrete example. Just trying to help you in your search. You can search for derive and ladder in the [JavaFX CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textfield).